# Doubled link list C++

Tags: linked-list

I am creating a templated doubly linked list (just for practice).

I have 2 classes, ListClass & NodeClass

```
template < class T >
class ListClass
{
  private:
    NodeClass < T > *head;
    NodeClass < T > *tail;

  public:
    //some member functions
    //my question will deal with the member function called insert(const T &val2Ins
};

template < class T >
class NodeClass
{
  private:
    data;
    NodeClass *next;
    NodeClass *prev;

  public:
    //some member functions (getter functions mostly)
};
```

I am trying to right an insert(const T &val2Ins) function for ListClass. This function is supposed to take in some value and "sorts" it in ascending order. Head points to the first node, which holds the smallest value. So from heat to tail is in ascending order.

I am having a very hard time working with these pointers and figuring out how to actually perform the linking. Inserting the node into an empty list is trivial, but once the list becomes populated, I am not sure how to perform the linking of the pointers. Could someone give me some advice on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply walk the list from head (or tail) using the pointers and compare the data. Note that I assume NodeClass has declared ListClass as friend (or you need to set up the getters and setters for private data members):

```
void insert(const T &val2Ins)
{
    using Node = NodeClass<T>;
    Node *next = head;

    while(next)
    {
        if(val2Ins < next->data)
        {
            Node *n = new Node;
            n->previous = next->previous;
            n->next = next;
            next->previous = n;
            return;
        }

        next = next->next;
    }

    if(!next)
    {
        Node *n = new Node;
        n->previous = tail;

        if(tail)
            tail->next = n;
        else
            tail = n;

        if(!head)
            head = n;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I cannot use "friend" (per my instructions).

Comment: The functions for NodeClass consist of 1) NodeClass(NodeClass *inPrev, const T &inVal, NodeClass *inNext) a constructor that takes previous pointer, next pointer, value, and assigns them to current node.   2) T getVal()     3) NodeClass* getNextPtr()   4) NodeClass* getPrevPtr()    5) void setNextPtr2Null()  6) void setPrevPtrToNull()    7) void setBeforeAndAfterPtrs()

Comment: one question I have is you have the following Node *next = head;, followed by while(next). My issue is this function is called after insertion of the first element of the list, but when I insert this value, I also set this first node's prev&next pointers to NULL, which means the node that head is pointing to does not point to anything. So wouldn't while(head)=while(false)=while(temp)?

Comment: @nm17 Not the most elegant solution but I made it so it handles the empty list as well. If you cannot use friend than use the accessors and setters you list in your first comment instead of direct access I use.

Comment: Wait, is your "Next" variable the private member variable of NodeClass, or is it some new variable you defined?

Comment: @nm17 It is local variable of type NodeClass<T>, see beginning of the function. "using" has replaced typedef for aliasing types, I simply say that Node = NodeClass<T> so I do not have to type it again and again in full.